# What is the MIPS assembly that would be generated for the following sequence of code: f = g + 2*h - A[3]

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I have to write  the MIPS assembly that would be generated for the following sequence of code: `f = g + 2*h - A[3]`

I wrote the following sequence.

```
lw   $t0, 12($s6)       # Load the address of A[3] into $t0, which is $s6 + 12 (3*4 bytes). 

lw   $t1, 0($t0)          # Load the value stored at the address of A[3] into $t1.

add  $t2, $s2, $s2     # Multiply h by 2 and store the result in $t2.

add  $t3, $s1, $t2     # Add g and the result of h*2 and store the result in $t3.

sub  $s0, $t3, $t1     # Subtract the result of g + 2*h from A[3] and store into f.
```

I want to know if Is it ok?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Compile it and see for yourself. Use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) if you don't want to install the necessary compiler on your computer.

Comment: Too much dereferencing.  There's two `lw`'s in a row and only one is needed if `A`'s address is already in `$s6`.  You're doing `*A[3]` instead of `A[3]`.